# Finding $\Theta$ of Recurrence $ T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{3})+2T(\frac{2n}{3})+n$ or finding Closed Form for $2^{p+1}+2=3^p$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

The goal is to get an exact asymptotic for $T(n).$  I tried two approaches, but both failed:

1). Recursion tree. We see that $$\sum_{i = 0}^{\log_{3}(n)}n2^i=\Theta(n^{1+\log_3(2)})<<T(n) << \sum_{i = 0}^{\log_{3/2}(n)} n2^i = \Theta(n^{1+\log_{3/2}(2)})$$ but cannot, as I can see, get $\Theta(T(n))$ exactly.

2). Akra-Bazzi Theorem. We get through straightforward calculus that $T(n) = \Theta(n^p)$ where $2+2^{p+1} = 3^p$. As far as I can see this equation yields no closed form for $p\,$ (But it gives a numerical approximation consistent with 1, so that is good).

The goal is to get a closed form better than $2^{p+1}+2 = 3^p.$ I believe such a closed form does exist, for reasons associated with the expected difficulty of the problem, and that it can be found through an alternate derivation, transformations or some other trick.

Summary:
Twin goals of the question, any answer resolving either will be accepted:

(1). Can this problem be solved without the use of the Akra-Bazzi Theorem?

(2). Find a better closed form for $p$.

Essentially, I have a hunch that getting (1) leads right to (2).

Any help is appreciated.

This is  problem 2(m) from [Jeffrey Erickson's notes](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/notes/99-recurrences.pdf).

Comment: All the information I can find doesn't say anything about restricting $p$ to be integral - it need only be a real number. Apparently $2.19629$ is the approximate value for $p$ in your case. All other needed hypotheses appear to be satisfied, so you can use the Akra-Bazzi theorem.

Comment: In particular I get that your algorithm is ~$\Theta(x^{2.19629})$ (after dropping the less significant term resulting from the integration). Seems that the absence of an "$h$-function" and the simplicity of the "$g$-function" makes for very simple asymptotics. Also, how did I never know about this result 'til now??

Comment: @Chris I know it doesn't have to be integral, I want to find an exact form for p. What are you talking about with "h functions" and "g functions?"

Comment: We can use the Akra-Bazzi theorem to find the exact asymptotic of your function: it's $\Theta(x^p)$, where $p$ is the solution of $2 + 2^{x+1} = 3^x$. This *is* the exact form of $p$. (And as for $g$ and $h$, I was referring to the choice of variable names in the Wikipedia article and the paper of Akra-Bazzi for two components of the recurrence.)

Comment: @Chris I think it is possible to get a "better" closed form of p. I actually got this from Jeffrey Erickson's notes on solving recurrences(I'll add a link in the question), in which this is a starred problem. Since everything I've done so far is completely straightforward, I think there is a more complete solution.

Comment: What is $T(1)$?

Comment: @uniquesolution doesn't matter. We are looking for $\Theta(T(n))$, and base cases only change $T(n)$ by a constant factor(as long as they're greater than zero).

Comment: "The goal is to get a closed form better than $2^{p+1}+2 = 3^p$. I believe such a closed form does exist" Why such a belief? If the quoted passage is your question, then this should be closed, I am afraid.

Comment: @Did I believe it is possible because the question is supposed to be difficult(a "starred" problem). What I have done is easy. Regardless, it is a valid question whether such a closed form exists, and if it does, how to find it. I'll modify my question to make it clear that is what I am asking.

Comment: Proving that $p$ exists and is unique is trivial. And, as often, there is no explicit formula for $p$.

Comment: @Did Often there isn't. But I want to know in this case, and I have reason to believe there is a better form.

Comment: I was not speaking in general but about the specific case of your question. Anyway, since you say you "have reason(s) to believe there is a better form", you should explain these reasons.

Comment: I never actually used the words "exact form." My question makes it clear what I am asking.

Comment: I suspect you would get a much more useful response if the question was framed as looking for a closed form solution of $2 + 2^{p+1} = 3^p$ rather than framed as asking for the solution to a recurrence relation which you've already solved.

Comment: @Hurkyl the trouble is that if I phrase it that way I get told "That is the closed form of p!" And solving this recurence without Akra-Bazzi is still an interesting question.

Comment: @A.W.Grossbard: But this way, you turned aside all of the people who might be knowledgeable about such equations but aren't knowledgeable or interested in solving recursions, and you've disillusioned all of the people who are eager to solve recursions (such as the two deleted answers!) when they learn you've already solved it... and you got told that anyways!

Comment: What means "a closed form" ? The equation $2+2^{p+1}=3^p$ *is* the solution, but written implicitly because no explicit expression for $p$ exists (beside you define one yourself).

Comment: If you can prove that, it would be a very good answer.

Comment: @A.W.Grossbard: The situation is: $\,a\cosh x= b^x\,$ $(a,b>0, b\neq 1, b\ne e^n, n$ not rational$)$ , here: $\,4\cosh((p/2)\ln 2)=(3/\sqrt{2})^p $ . There is no term of well-known functions to solve that for x (generally) .

Comment: "My question makes it clear what I am asking" Actually it does not. What is clear however is that when you first posted this you expected an exact explicit formula for $p$ (for reasons you never made explicit, despite being asked) and that you now have somewhat lowered your expectations (or at least your formulation of them), since you now invoke the rather vague "a better closed form". Not that this will change much in the end...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal to get a closed form better than $\,2+2^{p+1}=3^p\,$ is impossible  because $\,T(n)=An^p-n\,$ is the general *solution* (and the Akra-Bazzi Theorem is *not* necessary to get this).

E.g. the recursion of the Fibonacci numbers is a good example how to get such formulas. The given link above (*Jeffrey Erickson's notes*) is good too to understand how to solve such recursions.

For a *closed* form for $\,p\,$ define a function $\,f(x):=\sqrt[x]{4\cosh x}\,$ for $\,x>0\,$ and $\,f^{-1}(x)\,$ it's inverse function so that one gets:  $$p=\frac{2}{\ln 2}f^{-1}(\sqrt[\ln2]{4.5})$$

---

*Did* $\,$gave me the good advice to add a proof for the (descending) monotony of $\,f(x)\,$ .

It's enough to proof this for $\,\ln f(x)\,$ because of $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}f(x)=f(x)\frac{d}{dx}\ln f(x)\,$ and $\,f(x)>0\,$ .

We have to proof $\,\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}\ln f(x)<0\,$ for all $\,x>0\,$ .

$\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}\ln f(x)=-\frac{\ln (4\cosh x)}{x^2}+\frac{\tanh x}{x}<0\enspace$ is true because of

$x\tanh x<x<\ln(2 e^x)<\ln(4\cosh x)\enspace$ or in details

$e^x-e^{-x}<e^x+e^{-x}\,$ , $\enspace x<x+\ln 2\,$ , $\enspace e^x<2\cosh x\,$ .

Comment: @A.W.Grossbard , additional comment: Point (1) is solved, for point (2) I showed a possibility of a closed form, and your sentence "... that getting (1) leads right to (2)." is right. So, what is left of your question ? :-)

Comment: Another "closed form", simpler and at least as useful: consider $$g(x)=\left(\frac13\right)^x+\left(\frac23\right)^x$$ then $$p=g^{-1}\left(\frac12\right)$$ Note that the fact that $g$ indeed has an inverse is direct, by contrast the fact that $f$ has an inverse, while true, should be established.

Comment: @Did : Thanks for your note. It's clear that we have a lot of possibilities here but I wanted to get rid of the $+$ (that's the reason for the complicate form). :-)

Comment: Why "getting rid of the $+$", whatever that means, would be desirable or even relevant?

Comment: @Did: Numerically not relevant, *of course*. I also thought first about what you've defined $g(x)$ (it's nice to discuss that and it looks clear and it seems to be better for getting an approximation for the inverse) but the definition of $f(x)$ looks more compact (nearer to a "closed form") because we have the well known $\cosh$ together with the power of $1/x$ in contrast to $(1/3)^x$ and  $(2/3)^x$ which are connected as if they didn't have much to do with each other. In other words: *A definition here is as good as the other in principle, it's quality is only determined by the purpose.*

Comment: @Did: Thanks for your help ! :-)